# Insert variables in a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I created a 2D array: `3` columns and `222` rows (see code). And now I would like to insert in the first row `0,0,0`. How can I do this.

So far I have this:

```
public float[,] arrayPosSpheres = new float[222, 3];

//array row one with zeros 
arrayPosSpheres [0] =  [0,0,0];
```

Later on I would like to have access to this values in my array. So for example Row one and column 2. How can I do this?

**Edit:**

```
// Update is called once per frame (ORIGINAL) 
void Update()
{
    int initialpos = 10; 
    //create an array with 3 columns (x,y,z) and numberOfPoints rows 
    //Vector3[] arrayPosSpheres=new Vector3[(int)(20/(sizeSphere*overlay))]; 

    for (int j = 0; j < 221; j++) 
    {
        arrayPosSpheres [j] = arrayPosSpheres [j + 1]; 
    } 

    float functionXvalue = 221 * scaleInputRange / 222; 
    if (animate) 
    {
        functionXvalue += Time.time * animSpeed; 
    }

    arrayPosSpheres [221]=   Vector3 (functionXvalue,ComputeFunction(functionXvalue)*scaleResult,0); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 221; i++)
    {
        arrayPosSpheres [i] = arrayPosSpheres [i + 1];
    }

    for (int m = 221; m = 0; m--) 
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < 3; q++)
        { 
            // access of x,y and z values of sphere 221 
            plotPoints[m].transform.position = arrayPosSpheres[m][q]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to specify the language you're using. I for one don't recognize that array syntax.

Comment: sorry. I use c#. More precisely, c# in Unity.

Comment: Once creating the array as numeric (in this case float) type, all the values in the array are already 0 so no need to do it except if it already contains values and you want to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I need two loops I think, one for to access the rows and one to access the columns.

Would something like this be correct:

```
//
public float[,] arrayPosSpheres = new float[222, 3];


GameObject[] plotPoints;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    //array row one with zeros 
    arrayPosSpheres [0][0] = 0;
    arrayPosSpheres [0][1] = 0; 
    arrayPosSpheres [0][2] = 0; 


    //fill whole array with zeros 
    for (int k = 1; k <= 221; k++) {

        for (int s = 1; s <= 3; s++) {

            arrayPosSpheres [k] [s] = arrayPosSpheres [k - 1] [s - 1];

        }


    }
```

My aim is to have in the first row as I said zeros. And then I would fill my array with zeros based on the zeros in the first row.

Comment: I understood what you did with the for loop. But how do I continue when I would use two loops to fill my array with the zeros of the 0. Line?

Comment: I would like that just sphere 222 is moving in a sine wave manner and all the other spheres would take the position of the sphere for t-1. Do you see what I mean? Sorry for these explanations...